# How to detect that a new VC is pushed by the MoreController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to invoke a certain method whenever the user selects a different tab of a UITabBarController. The following works for actual tabs on the tab bar but not for the 'tabs' on the More controller:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
     [self doSomethingWhenAnotherVCIsSelected]
}
```

This method seems only to be called when a 'tab' is selected, including the 'more' tab. Whenever another VC on the 'more' tab is pushed, this is not called.

Is there any standard notification mechanism that can be used to detect if a VC was selected on the 'more' tab?

Answer (score 1):

Call the method in the -viewWillAppear of the viewController.

Comment: This works but I would need to add it to each and every view controller. I meanwhile found a simple way to hook into the UIMoreNavigationController, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following workaround:

```
// subclass of UITabBarController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    moreDelegate=self.moreNavigationController.delegate;
    self.moreNavigationController.delegate=self;
    ...
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [moreDelegate navigationController:navigationController willShowViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [moreDelegate navigationController:navigationController didShowViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    [self tabBarController:self didSelectViewController:viewController];
}
```